# complicated custom filter for nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've stuck for this for 2 days, tried so many ways still couldn't get it right. I can't change the API data so I have to deal with front end handling. I really need some help.

```
  $scope.stationary = [{
    "name": "Pen",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 25
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 21
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Color Pencil",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 3
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Color Pencil Special",
    "data": [{
      "date": "1-10-2017",
      "inventory": 2
    }, {
      "date": "2-10-2017",
      "inventory": 1 // make this view to '-' since inventory of color pencil is zero
    }]
  }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/op2zd2vr/

The case is if color pencil's inventory is zero, should display '-' on color pencil special column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Updated Answer**:

```
myApp.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(items) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            for (var k = 0; k < items[i].data.length; k++) {
                if (i != 0 && items[i - 1].data[k].inventory == 0) {
                    items[i].data[k]['isZero'] = true;
                } else {
                    items[i].data[k]['isZero'] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

See `Updated jsfiddle` [link](https://jsfiddle.net/avnesh2/zfn0mzob/2/).

It's working for me.

Comment: you missed understood the question. Should apply '-' on the bottom column of 0, not the 0 itself. In my case it should be `0` on 2-10-2017 for color pencil special.

Comment: You want to put **-** for `name: Color Pencil Special` if `inventory` is **0** for `name: Color Pencil`?

Comment: No, the inventory column of color pencil special. It's the bottom right most column.

Comment: I think you better give an example of the resulting table in your question, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RonDadon look at below answer, F3L1X79 has got the question right, I think what I want is easy to understand.

Comment: @JennyMok OK, so if we take that as an example, what should happen if "pen" has 0 inventory?

Comment: then show it's original value, which in my case it's 1

Comment: @JennyMok so what is the logic? If "X" has inventory 0 than "X Special" has inventory "-"? Because you commented to F3L1X79 that the data can change, if it can change, then there should be some logic otherwise it is impossible to guess.

Comment: @RonDadon the output of F3l1X79 is correct, but it's not acceptable. I can do the hack to get the output but that's bad. What I want is a directive that can is reusable. color pencil special's inventory depends on color pencil. I think I explain it clearly.

Comment: @JennyMok But that is what he did - he solved that dependency. Directive or filter is really not effective here, because to make a directive or a filter that will do it "automatically" means that is will be processed on every digest cycle in angular, and will go over the same function times the length of the array - that is really not efficient! You better go with his solution to process the data once before assigning it to the view. Re-usability is great, but not at such high price and not for every use case.

Comment: But if the datas are 0 in first row ('Pen') , this will still display a '-' in the second row ('Color Pencil')... Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have to manipulate the datas itselves, you cannot simply use a filter for this particular case.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/op2zd2vr/2/

Solution used (depending ont the datas' names):

```
var positions = [];
$scope.stationary.forEach(function (s) {
     if(s.name === 'Color Pencil'){
        for(var i = 0; i < s.data.length; i++){
          if(s.data[i].inventory === 0){
            positions.push(i);
          }
        }
     }
     if(s.name === 'Color Pencil Special'){
        for(var i = 0; i < s.data.length; i++){
          if(positions.indexOf(i) >= 0){
            s.data[i].inventory = '-';
          }
        }
     }
  });
```

Comment: this is not a good solution, what if in the future the data change? that's the point I'm writing a directive, so it's reusable.

Comment: don't feel I should hardcode the name like this. I need a directive :(

Comment: You just have to store the names as constants and create a function using theses constants and my loops?